# How do I get command+tab to stop re-ordering spaces

Tags: macos, spaces

Right now I have Chrome set up in Desktop 1, Terminal in Desktop 2, and Spotify in Desktop 3.  If I command+tab to Spotify, it changes the order of the desktops, so now Desktop 3 is Desktop 2 and Desktop 2 is Desktop 3.  This is frustrating because I expected them to stay put.  What I would like to have happen when I command+tab to Spotify is have it go to Desktop 3 and not reorder the Desktops.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can change the default preference easily:

System Prefs > Mission Control > Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use.

[image]

Comment: yesss! hate this so much!